# Convert varchar to be float

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got this error when trying to convert varchar to float using cast or convert:

> Error converting data type varchar to float.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Which data are you trying to convert? Which query are you running? Please provide these critical pieces of information, otherwise your question is too broad.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `try_convert()`:

```
select try_convert(float, col)
```

If this fails, the functions returns `NULL` but the query continues processing.